# Generating DDL/DML scripts for all tables/columns in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is mostly an experiment I've made to learn some SQL Server concepts. Suppose the following scenario:

- I have a production database, a development database and a test database;
- The development database is more updated than the test database, containing several new tables and columns that were recently developed;
- I would like to update the test database as well (with these new tables and columns), but would rather not drop and recreate that DB (it contains useful test data)

The script I wrote below is executed against the "development" database so that it will generate a script with conditions for every column of the database. The script should then be used against the other database to update it, and the conditions should add whatever column or table that the test database doesn't already have:

```
DECLARE @CURRENT_COLUMN nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @COLUMN_LITERAL nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @CURRENT_DEFAULT nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @CURRENT_DATATYPE nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @CURRENT_SCHEMA nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SQLA nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLB nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @CURRENT_TABLE nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @COMPUTED smallint
SET @COMPUTED = 0
PRINT '
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
'
DECLARE CUR_SCHEMA CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

OPEN CUR_SCHEMA

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_SCHEMA
    INTO @CURRENT_SCHEMA

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   


DECLARE CUR_TAB CURSOR FOR
SELECT ist.TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ist 
WHERE ist.TABLE_SCHEMA = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 name
        FROM sys.tables
        where name = ist.TABLE_NAME)
ORDER BY ist.TABLE_NAME

OPEN CUR_TAB

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TAB
    INTO @CURRENT_TABLE


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

      PRINT '
      IF OBJECT_ID('''+@CURRENT_TABLE+''') IS NULL
      BEGIN
      SET @SQL = ''
      CREATE TABLE [' + @CURRENT_TABLE +'] (placeholder bit)''
      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
      END 
      '

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc

OPEN CUR

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
    INTO @CURRENT_COLUMN, @CURRENT_DATATYPE
    SET @COLUMN_LITERAL = '[' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + ']'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQLB = ''
    SET @COMPUTED = 0

     /* Check if column is computed */

      IF (SELECT is_computed FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@CURRENT_TABLE)
      AND name = @CURRENT_COLUMN) = 1
      BEGIN
      SET @SQLB = @SQLB + 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
        INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
        WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
        AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
        AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
       ADD ' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + ' AS ' +
      (SELECT definition FROM sys.computed_columns
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@CURRENT_TABLE)
      AND name = @CURRENT_COLUMN)

      SET @COMPUTED = 1

      END

      /* Check for identity */

      IF (SELECT is_identity FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@CURRENT_TABLE)
      AND name = @CURRENT_COLUMN) = 1
      BEGIN
      SET @SQLB = @SQLB + ' IDENTITY (' + 
      CAST((SELECT IDENT_SEED(@CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']')) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ',' +
      CAST((SELECT IDENT_INCR(@CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']')) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ')'
      END

      /* Check if NULL is allowed */

      IF (SELECT sc.is_nullable from sys.columns sc
        INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types sp ON sp.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
        WHERE st.name = @CURRENT_TABLE
        AND sc.name = @CURRENT_COLUMN
        AND ss.name = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
        AND sp.name = @CURRENT_DATATYPE
      ) = 0
      BEGIN
      SET @SQLB = @SQLB + ' NOT NULL'
      END
      ELSE SET @SQLB = @SQLB + ' NULL' 

      /*  Check for defaults  */

      IF (SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @CURRENT_COLUMN
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
      AND TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE) IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN
      SET @CURRENT_DEFAULT = ' DEFAULT ' + (SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @CURRENT_COLUMN
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
      AND TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE)

      END
ELSE SET @CURRENT_DEFAULT = ''


 IF @CURRENT_DATATYPE in ('date','datetime2','datetime','time',
      'smalldatetime','datetimeoffset','text','ntext',
      'varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')

  BEGIN

        /*  Check for date related data types  */

   IF @CURRENT_DATATYPE in ('date','datetime2','datetime','time',
      'smalldatetime','datetimeoffset')
      BEGIN
      SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.['+ @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
        ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+' '+@CURRENT_DEFAULT

      END

      /*  Check for MAX column length  */

  IF (SELECT sc.max_length FROM sys.columns sc
INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.types sp ON sp.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
WHERE st.name = @CURRENT_TABLE
AND sc.name = @CURRENT_COLUMN
AND ss.name = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
AND sp.name = @CURRENT_DATATYPE) = -1

BEGIN

SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.['+ @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
        ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+'(MAX)'+' ' + @CURRENT_DEFAULT
END

      /*  Check for string data types  */

ELSE IF @CURRENT_DATATYPE in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')
BEGIN
SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
        ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+''
        + '(' + 
        CAST( 
         ( SELECT 
         CASE WHEN @CURRENT_DATATYPE IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar') THEN MAX(sc.max_length)/2
         ELSE MAX(sc.max_length) END AS 'max_length' FROM sys.columns sc
        INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types sp ON sp.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
        WHERE st.name = @CURRENT_TABLE
        AND sc.name = @CURRENT_COLUMN
        AND ss.name = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
        AND sp.name = @CURRENT_DATATYPE
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(10)) +')'+@CURRENT_DEFAULT

END

     /*  Check for text and ntext types (no column width)  */

ELSE IF @CURRENT_DATATYPE in ('text','ntext')
BEGIN
SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
        ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+' '+@CURRENT_DEFAULT

END


  END
ELSE

        /*  Check for decimal and numeric types  */

IF @CURRENT_DATATYPE in ('decimal','numeric')
  BEGIN


SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE '  + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
         ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+''+'(' + CAST( (SELECT MIN(NUMERIC_PRECISION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @CURRENT_COLUMN
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @CURRENT_SCHEMA
        AND DATA_TYPE = @CURRENT_DATATYPE
        ) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + 

        CAST( (SELECT MIN(NUMERIC_SCALE) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @CURRENT_COLUMN
        AND DATA_TYPE = @CURRENT_DATATYPE
        ) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'+ @CURRENT_DEFAULT

  END
ELSE  
  BEGIN
SET @SQLA = '
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + '''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + '.[' + @CURRENT_TABLE + ']
        ADD '+@COLUMN_LITERAL+'' + ' ' + ''+@CURRENT_DATATYPE+''+@CURRENT_DEFAULT


END

IF @COMPUTED = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT @SQLA + @SQLB + '
    END
    '


END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
    INTO @CURRENT_COLUMN, @CURRENT_DATATYPE
    SET @COLUMN_LITERAL = '[' + @CURRENT_COLUMN + ']'

END 
CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;

 PRINT '
    IF EXISTS
    (SELECT TOP 1 sc.name FROM sys.columns sc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
    WHERE sc.Name = ''placeholder''
    AND st.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+ @CURRENT_TABLE+ ''')
    AND ss.name = ''' + @CURRENT_SCHEMA + ''')
            BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE '+@CURRENT_SCHEMA+'.['+@CURRENT_TABLE+'] DROP COLUMN [placeholder]
            END

            '

   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TAB
   INTO @CURRENT_TABLE

END
CLOSE CUR_TAB
DEALLOCATE CUR_TAB

END
CLOSE CUR_SCHEMA
DEALLOCATE CUR_SCHEMA
```

Questions:

- Could my use of a "placeholder" column be avoided? (I added it because I couldn't create empty columns in case they didn't exist).
- Is the use of three cursors accepted? I believe this could be simplified, perhaps with temp tables, or table variables.
- Is my approach to catch exceptional formatting cases (like the numeric data type definition or the maximum column character length) cohesive?
- Is the script fully correct? I intensively tested it against a copy of a real database and also tested the script it generated against a blank database, and it seems to have produced the expected results.
- Is the number of variables I used excessive? Is any of my variables irrelevant?
- Is the use of both **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** and **system tables** acceptable? (I used **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** some times to avoid excess of table joining).
- Am I using cursors correctly?
- Would you suggest a different approach to some section of my script?

Thanks, and sorry for asking so many questions. Answer just one or some if you don't wish to answer all of them!

** *NOTES* **

- I wrote this for an SQL Server 2008 database, but you could point out alternatives for newer versions to help improve my knowledge
- I know this script doesn't replicate stored procedures, triggers, and other things, but that could be scripted automatically with SSMS afterwards so I included just column properties on the script.

Comment: Or you could just purchase something like sql compare from redgate which will do all of this for you. The code you posted seems to miss a lot of really important things like constraints, foreign keys, primary keys, indexes. It also has some serious problems with schemas. If you have the same table name in two schemas your code to get the columns will be all mixed up because you don't specify the schema.

Comment: I know about sqlcompare (never purchased it though). I made the script as an experiment, and as I pointed out I don't really care about things like foreign keys, primary keys and indexes because SSMS can script that and I could just run its script on top of it. About schemas, the first cursor **CUR_SCHEMA** enforces iteration of every schema and each table in that schema (or at least is supposed to, gotta test it further).

Comment: No it won't work. Your query "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @CURRENT_TABLE ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc" will return rows from all tables with the same name regardless of which schema it is in.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add a condition for the @CURRENT_SCHEMA variable there, now I have included it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I would propose the usage of the Sql Server Data Tools and database project. It allows you to import a schema of existing database or create a new database project. You can link it to the TFS or Git, your preference for source control. In this case you do not have to have a separate SQL script to generate schema. If you decide to move to the schema development from SSDT then the codebase will always have a latest known schema. You can then generate scripts for deployment of the new codebase and SSDT or Visual Studio will figure the SQL out, I would strongly recommend checking those scripts before deployment to prod.
It is also possible to publish changes to target databases from this tool.

[SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: I have forgotten to mention that in the properties you can specify which SQL Server version your project is targeting, so it can be 2008 or 2012 or 2014 or 2016. Project will then look for a code which can or cannot be used in a given version of SQL Server. Alternative to this is the Redgate

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely give it a try! You however wouldn't recommend query-based schema copying, then?

Comment: @Dariusz I'll second that solution with the exception of tables bigger than a few TB (they need scripts so you get the best method otherwise it takes too long to deploy)

Comment: I tried SSDT but there are a lot of problems with certain database objects that have references to non accessible databases. I can't just replicate the schema ignoring such referencing "issues"?

Comment: You are correct. You should not ignore reference issues, but investigate them, if possible. What we have found was that in some databases there where a lot of object, which where referencing non existent sprocs, views, or fields, hence sst allowed us to identify and fix those nuggets. Further more, if the name of the object is tree part, and it is referencing its own database it will also throw an error, so we remove the references. If there are objects looking at different databases we had to bring those databases as well and add them as references.

Comment: I think that there is an option in ssdt to ignore the errors and progress with the build and generation of code, however we have chosen to clean the code base, as this also have addressed the issue of build up of technical debt, and speed of development. Hope this helps and sorry for late answer.